# org-pretty-entities for markdown-mode

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, markdown-mode

org-mode has the variable `org-pretty-entities` that allows for the display of LaTeX math as unicode characters. How could one get the same result in markdown-mode? It seems like this should be a default option, and yet I can't find anything in the documentation for markdown-mode or from googling around.